# WebBrowser control: window.external access array

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, window.external

I'm trying to access an array from C# in Javascript.

That's the JavaScript code:

```
var testArray = window.external.testfunction();
for(var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    alert(testArray[i]);
}
```

I tested it with following C# object assigned to the ObjectForScripting property:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class TestObject
{
    public string[] testfunction()
    {
        var test = new string[1];
        test[0] = "test";
        return test;
    }
}
```

Already when trying to access `testArray.length` it throws an JavaScript error saying "function expected".

So how can I return an array back to the JavaScript code?

The JavaScript code is fix (I cannot modify it). So the function will be called with `window.external.testfunction()` and as return value the JavaScript code expects an array.

How can I accomplish that from the C# side?

Best regards and thank you for any ideas on that

Andreas

Comment: The easiest way would be to wrap you C# array into a separate object with `Get`/`Set`/`Length` methods, and return it to JavaScript. This could give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20943173/1768303

Comment: Hello Noseratio, I don't think that this works, because then JavaScript probably will not be able to access the array elements by using `testArray[i]`, does it? As I wrote I cannot change the JavaScript code itself, I just can work with the C# code. But is there really no way to pass an array as return value of a function to JavaScript?

Comment: If you can't modify JavaScript, how are you going to access `window.external`? Anyhow, you can always inject some new JavaScript, check the update at the end of my answer.

Comment: Just to answer your question why there are acccess to `window.external` in the JS code already although I can't modify it: this JS code is inside a bigger project which uses some external data already through this `window.external` interface. I just need to simulate or mock this inteface now for testing purpose from the C# side. That's the reason why I can't modify the JS code, but the `window.external` are already in place and cannot be changed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't think that this works, because then JavaScript probably will
>   not be able to access the array elements by using testArray[i], does
>   it?

The object I mentioned in the comment would be the *easiest* way, but you would not be able to access its elements as `testArray[i]` from JavaScript.

The *hard* way would be implement a class in C# which simulates JavaScript array object (so it is exposed to JavaScript as COM `IDispatchEx` object and is accessible as `testArray[i]`). Such C# class would need to implement `IReflect` and `IExpando` managed interfaces. If you want to go this route, I posted some more details here:

- [Exposing c# anonymous class objects to COM (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633071/exposing-c-sharp-anonymous-class-objects-to-com-javascript)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067386/1768303
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18546866/1768303

Yet another way of doing this. Despite you cannot modify the page's existing JavaScript, you still can [inject some new JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002650/1768303), and do with it whatever you want.

Comment: I probably will need to go the IExando way. Therefore I checked your examples and the second link is a really good example to start with IReflect, but I did not find an example (also while searching on Google for it) for an implementation of IExpando. Do you know an example on how to "simulate" the array behavior - so access elements by `testArray[i]` - by using this interface?

Comment: @ab-tools, `IReflect` might enough for a "fixed" array (i.e., JavaScript can't add new elements, but can read/write existing ones). Keep in mind that element indexes are mapped to properties with names `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. `IExpando` is needed if you want to add new elements to the array. I can't find an example of `IExpando`, but I'm certain I coded in the past and it worked.

Comment: Hello Noseratio, first thanks for your great support! I definitely do not need to add any new elements here - so IReflect should be enough. But I don't get it to work with the example from your link: what should I use as target object there? Basically I don't have a target object - I just want to simulate the array behavior. It would be great if you could give me some hints here. Thanks again very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Still marked your answer as accepted as you gave me the tip (using IReflect) I needed to find the right way. Thanks for that again!

Answer (score 1):

I really got it to work now myself with the IReflect interface! :-)

You need to implement the methods `GetProperties` and `InvokeMember` yourself: in `GetProperties` you need to make sure there is a property returned with the name "length" and a property for "0" till the length-1 of the array. In `InvokeMember` you just check then which method JavaScript wants to call and return the correct result.

The biggest problem I had was that the class `PropertyInfo` is abstract - so I can't create a new object out of it. So I needed to derive an own class from it and use that to return custom property names.